# Проверка наличия записи в БД Mysql на php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, бот

Пишу телеграм-бота на php, который должен выдавать информацию находится человек в базе данных или нет.

Запись в БД реализована. Как реализовать проверку?

Comment: SELECT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = 1)

Comment: Благодарю! Попробую!

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой и лучший в плане быстродействия метод - это использовать COUNT()

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM users WHERE user_id = 1';

if($sql && $sql["num"] > 0) {
    echo "Пользователь найден";
} else {
  echo "Нет такого пользователя";
}
```